# python3 os.chdir throwing a syntax error when using a variable

Tags: python, directory, syntax-error, python-3.4

I'm trying to remove numbers from files in a given directory.
For some reason whenever I try pass a variable into os.chdir I get a syntax error.

I have tried converting the norm_direc to a str using str() to no avail. 
I researched online but could only find people getting errors for forgetting their quotation marks but as I understand it they're not needed for a variable.

Source Code;

```
#Setup
import os
import datetime
print ("Started on "+ str(datetime.datetime.now()))

#Get the norms
norm_direc = os.getcwd()
file_list = os.listdir(r"/home/damhan/Downloads/Tyler - Wolf 2013")


def rename_files():
        #Workings
        os.chdir("/home/damhan/Downloads/Tyler - Wolf 2013")

        #Start the loop
        for file_name in file_list:
                os.rename(file_name, file_name.strip("0123456789")

        #Cleanup
        os.chdir(norm_direc)
rename_files()
print("Done :)")
```

The error;

```
  File "numberdestroyer.py", line 20
    os.chdir(norm_direc)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing a closing bracket in:

```
 os.rename(file_name, file_name.strip("0123456789") #<-- need one more )
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, thank you. Sometimes you just cant see it with your own eyes.